# Long string inserts and lookups in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

New to Mongodb. Would there be perceivable performance drawbacks to inserting strings that are about **100** characters long and doing lookups of documents based on that string vs inserting strings that are about **16** characters long and doing lookups of documents based on that string?

I have a marginally compelling reason to store user ID's as unique hrefs which are about 100 characters long. However, I could parse those hrefs to obtain a unique ID about 16 characters long and insert them then -- but then, the href that I am removing may become important at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of value affects the index size for the corresponding key. *100* characters will lead to smaller maximum effective index size. While the index fits in memory entirely you will not get any performance drop regardless value size.